# Evaluating sum for a df['column'] through cumsum() (or any other such function) according to a specific condition. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

My data is related to "Cricket", A sports which is popular in India. It has 20 overs for each inning max and each over has approx 6 balls (can vary).

*dataframe* has these cols,

```
season  match_id    inning  batting_team    bowling_team  total_runs_per_ball   sum_total_runs  sum_total_wickets   over/ball   runs_last_5     wickets_last_5
```

`sum_total_runs` is a cumsum() result of `total_runs_per_ball`.

`sum_total_wickets` is also cumsum() result of another query.

`runs_last_5` and `wickets_last_5`  are the newly created columns with 0 as preset value. I want to update both of these by determining their sum in last 5 overs.

First of all, *my data* looks like this (not showing some less important columns),

Lots of columns to show, so I am placing images instead.

`df.head`:
[image]

`df.tail`:
[image]

I don't know how to determine the last 5 overs by code. I am not showing rows before 5.1 (over/ball < 5.1). But `runs_last_5` and `wickets_last_5` will take data from there till over/ball 9.6, for 10.1 last 5 overs will be till 5.1. I mean, logically and verbally I know that if current over is 8.1, then the *runs_last_5* will be *sum_total_runs*  from 3.1 to 8.1 over/ball or if the current over/ball is 11.3 then the *runs_last_5* will be the *sum_total_runs* from 6.3 `over/ball` to 9.3 `over/ball`. Both `runs_last_5` and `wickets_last_5` will take this data from, `sum_total_runs` and `sum_total_wickets`.

`runs_last_5` and `wickets_last_5`     should look like,

In[]:   `df.head(10)`

out[]:

```
    sum_total_runs sum_total_wickets  runs_last_5   wickets_last_5
32    61            0                   59           0
33    61            1                   59           1
34    61            1                   59           1
35    61            1                   59           1
36    61            1                   58           1
37    61            1                   58           1
38    62            1                   55           1
39    63            1                   52           1
40    64            1                   47           1
41    66            1                   45           1
```

In[]:   `df.tail(10)`

out[]:

```
        sum_total_runs  sum_total_wickets   runs_last_5   wickets_last_5
75879   102             9                   31            4
75880   106             9                   35            4
75881   106             9                   35            4
75882   106             9                   31            4
75883   106             9                   30            4
75884   106             9                   29            4
75885   107             9                   29            4
75886   107             9                   28            4
75887   107             9                   24            4
75888   107             10                  23            5
```